# Load keras model in Java

Tags: keras, java

What are the requirements to load the trained model by `Keras` in Java?

I checked that `DeepLearning4J` supports `Keras` models, network architecture and weights can be easily loaded. The only cons are probably that we need to use `ND4J` backend or it does not matter?

If there is a created model using `keras` and `tensorflow`, what is the best way to load it in `Java ecosystem`?

I tried to use frozen graph script to save `tensorflow` model, but it cannot be loaded with `SavedModel.load`. Loading model as a Tensor Graph object seems to be common way, but available examples in Java are chaos especially when input is an image.

Comment: what format is your model in? Onnx?

Comment: are you using CPU or GPU?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Giving you some links which have worked:

[deploying-keras-deep-learning-models-with-java](https://towardsdatascience.com/deploying-keras-deep-learning-models-with-java-62d80464f34a) :  this uses DeepLearning4J, ND4J which supposedly you have tried already.

[tensorflow-keras-java](https://github.com/dhruvrajan/tensorflow-keras-java)

And same question is asked here - [converting-keras-in-python-to-java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51635187/converting-keras-in-python-to-java) . It uses `KerasModelImport.importKerasSequentialModelAndWeight`

You should give HDF5 file operation java examples: [hdf-java](https://support.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/examples/hdf-java.html) . It would be helpful if you want to change the weights yourself

Please comment if you have already tried all these already.